# How to get all <img> tags but exclude <img> tags under a <div> with an id of footer using xpath?

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping

Do you guys know how can I get all img tags but exclude img tags under a div with an id of footer using xpath?

Currently to get all img tags on an html page I do this:
`imgs = tree.xpath('//img')`

But I want to exclude all img tags under a div with an id of footer so I'm doing this one:

`imgs = tree.xpath('//*[not(div[@id="footer"])]//img')`        <- BUT THIS DOESN'T WORK

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should be something like:

```
imgs = tree.xpath('//img[not(parent::div[@id="footer"])]')
```

Breakdown:

- `//img` - search all `<img>` tags
- `[]` - where clause
- `not(parent::div[@id="footer"])` - not has a (direct) parent div with attribute id with value footer

---

If the `<div>` element is not the direct parent of `<img>` but one of it's parents, use:

```
imgs = tree.xpath('//img[not(ancestor::div[@id="footer"])]')
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. However I think its still not working because the results are still the same. Count of all img tags on the page is 85, count of all img tags under the div with an id of footer is 10, and when I tried your solution above, count is still 85 but it should be 75 only excluding the img tags under the div with an id of footer.

Comment: Hi sir! I now confirmed that your solution above was working. Thanks. However it only works if the img tags are the 1st child of the div with an id of footer. How can I exclude all the img tags under the div with an id of footer regardless if the img tags are its 1st child, 2nd child, 3rd child and so on?

Comment: Finally got it working by using ancestor - tree.xpath('//img[not(ancestor::div[@id="footer"])]')      Thanks markdark! :)